# how to find my own comments

Tags: support, comment, user-interface

Sometimes I just leave a comment on a question, (not an answer) and forget the question again.

but now I want to revisit the question. But could not find it.

How can I find the questions I have commented on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your own profile under activity is a list of your recent comments: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/88985/willemien?tab=activity&sort=comments

Answer (score 4):

On your profile page, click on the activity tab then on the comments box.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your profile page and then click on activity and select comments.

In your case you get to [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/88985/willemien?tab=activity&sort=comments).

Another way to access your activity page is to hover with your mouse above your name at the top of the page. Then you will be shown a window containing, among other things, a link to your activity page. (Of course, if you do this on this page, it will show your activity on meta.)